# Do I have t paste google analytics on evey page of my dgango app or just the base template?

Tags: django, google-analytics

Do I have to paste my ananlytics code into every page of my django app or can I just do it in one spot, the base, similar to disqus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the base page and that will be included in every actually generated page.

You can have, for example, a master_page.html in which you put the main wrapper HTML including your Google Analytics code.  The main part of your master page would have:

```
<html>
<head> 
<!-- Google Analytics code --> 
</head> 
<body>    
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Then your content page will have something like:

```
{% extends "master_page.html" %}
{% block content %}
 Your content for the page.
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I tried that and it only worked on the home page. I then tried using block template tags and it still didn't work. I'm going to try putting it on each page and report back with my results.